How to Send Email Notifications for Key Vault Expiration Dates 30 Days in Advance Using Logic App Flows?
I am new to Logic Apps and need assistance with a specific task. I need documentation or guidance on how to send email notifications for key vault expiration dates 30 days in advance to an email using Logic App flows.
Could someone provide the proper documentation or relevant Microsoft materials to help me set this up?
I have explored the azure documentation and Logic Apps documentation but haven't found a clear guide on how to set up this specific work flow.
Any example or templates that show this setup would be highly appreciated.

What specifically are you struggling with?

To get to know about expiry of KeyVault keys or secrets, you can use below design:

then you can use outlook to send an email:

Or you can get Validity end time using Get Metadata for a secret as below and then use outlook if it is less than 30 days:

Note:
To make this work you need to give RBAC Key Vault Administrator role for accessing the keyvault for logic app.
For further information refer this SO-thread's answer provided by me.

Hi Rithwik, Thanks for the your response. I have followed all the steps as mentioned. When I trigger the workflow, it states "workflow run timed out because the starting action was not performed. Please try again"

Not sure why you are manually triggering that and another thing is it will trigger automatically when it is near expiry, The workflow will trigger when the resource occurs, If you manually trigger it will timeout as no resource event occurred.
